# How to dynamically change the number of sliders in a Dash app depending on a dropdown

Tags: python, slider, plotly-dash

I am trying to learn Dash for a project, and would like to have a variable number of sliders relevant to the result of a dropdown box. So the user defines something, and then I present to them the appropriate number of sliders.

I present a minimal example, that generates 3 sliders, I would like this to update when the dropdown is used.

```
#Imports
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

# Defaults and function to generate 'default_num_sliders' sliders
default_num_sliders = 3
def generate_sliders(n_sliders = default_num_sliders):
    widgets = []
    for i in range(n_sliders):
        widgets.append(html.Label(html.Strong(f'Slider {i} Value'))),
        widgets.append(dcc.Slider(id=f'num_{i}', min=0, max=1, step=1))
    return widgets 


app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    # Drop down box to select the number of sliders
    html.Label(html.Strong('Number of sliders')),
    html.H1(''),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        [1,2,3,4,5],
        default_num_sliders,
        id='num_slider_dropdown',
    ),

   Generating sliders
   html.Div(generate_sliders(default_num_sliders), id='dynamic_sliders')
])


"""
Ideally the below function should update 'dynamic_sliders', but is commented out as presently it doesn't do anything but break the code. 
"""
# @app.callback(Input('num_slider_dropdown', 'value'))
# def update_num_sliders(value):
#     return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your code as below to make it work:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

# Defaults and function to generate 'default_num_sliders' sliders
default_num_sliders = 3
def generate_sliders(n_sliders = default_num_sliders):
    widgets = []
    for i in range(n_sliders):
        widgets.append(html.Label(html.Strong(f'Slider {i} Value'))),
        widgets.append(dcc.Slider(id=f'num_{i}', min=0, max=1, step=1))
    return widgets 


app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    # Drop down box to select the number of sliders
    html.Label(html.Strong('Number of sliders')),
    html.H1(''),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        [1,2,3,4,5],
        default_num_sliders,
        id='num_slider_dropdown',
    ),

   #Generating sliders
   html.Div(id='dynamic_sliders')
])


"""
Ideally the below function should update 'dynamic_sliders', but is commented out as presently it doesn't do anything but break the code. 
"""
@app.callback(Output('dynamic_sliders','children'), 
              Input('num_slider_dropdown', 'value'))
def update_num_sliders(value):
    return html.Div(generate_sliders(value)), 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

[image]

Comment: How would I then add callback including these sliders?